# delete Mat int function (opencv)

Tags: c++, opencv

If i create a function for example:

```
Mat func(const Mat& x, const Mat& y)
{
   Mat result;
   add(x,y,result);
   return result;
}
```

Will result be deleted correctly?

Comment: is there any reason why it shouldnt be?

Comment: I've just thinking because i have leaks memory in program and consider this could be a problem

Comment: i see. I was just wondering, because afaik its quite hard to get memory leaks or similar problems with variables on the stack

Comment: If you want to find memory leaks, use a tool like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to help you.

Comment: OpenCV Mat is a matrix header. In function `add`, the header will get an allocated data array according to the matrix size (will be equal to size of x here). This data array will not be freed at the end of `func`, because OpenCV Mat uses some kind of reference counting, so when `result`  goes out of scope there is another copy (or elision) so there is still a reference to the data array. BUT: when your returned Mat will later go out of scope and there is no more reference, the data array will be freed. OpenCV Mat typically doesn't leak memory for temporary created matrices because of that!

Comment: I dont have memory leaks. I'm writing genetic program where individual is represented by tree with leaf as Mat object. One tree have 2^(depth-1) Mat objects. When i create population - depth = 3 and 500 individuals, then i have allocated 2000 Mat objects. But i can only allocated 1738 object in the same time. So there is a problem.

Comment: I think you should either 1) load parts of your graph from disk only when needed, 2) use SparseMat to save a lot of memory if your Mat are sparse, 3) buy more RAM.

Answer (score 3):

Unless `Mat` itself leaks memory, or `add` does something truly horrible, it's fine. A `Mat` instance will be returned by the function, which can be used by the caller without having to worry about calling `delete` &c.

As for the function itself, a good compiler will *elide* the value copy of `Mat` that, conceptually, would otherwise be created due to `return result`.

With C++11 you can even provide a *move constructor* `Mat(Mat&&)` explicitly which helps prevent unnecessary value copies from being taken.